# Retrieving parents with properties

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I'm at point `Grandchild` below:

```
* Parent                                                           :@Project:
** Child
**** Grandchild
```

How can I construct an elisp function that goes up the hierarchy until it finds the first org header that directly has the `@Project` tag, and returns its name (i.e., in this case `"Parent"`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that does that:

```el
(defun get-parent ()
  (save-excursion
    (catch 'found
      (while (org-up-heading-safe)
        (when (and (member "@Project" (org-get-tags nil t))
                   (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp))
          (throw 'found (match-string-no-properties 4)))))))
```